# Lightswitch grid with complicated relationship

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have setup a database to catalouge books .. the database format involves having a table for Books, a table for authors, and a link table between the two, with bookid, and authorid, so each book can have multiple authors.
In Lightswitch I set up a datagrid to view by books table as usual, and there is the ability to add the authors in too (see screenshot as too hard to explain in text, but you hopefully know what I mean) .. but what happens is, in the grid the authors column is populated the same value for the author of the row that is selected at any time and obviously i want it to show the author for the book in that row.
Where am i going wrong?  There are no options I can see to change the binding, but I am new to LightSwitch.
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in this post is described exactly what you want to achieve: [how to create a many to many relationship](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2010/12/16/how-to-create-a-many-to-many-relationship-andy-kung.aspx)